# how to make my validator conditional for my checkbox control

Tags: java, jsf, xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have a validator defined for my checkbox control:

```
<xp:checkBox uncheckedValue="false"
    checkedValue="true" readonly="#{!matterBean.matter.editable}"
    id="cbKCSupport" style="width:100%"
    value="#{matterBean.matter.creatorKCSupport}"
    validator="#{matterValidators.valCreatorKCSupport}">
</xp:checkBox>
```

the method is nothing fancy, I just check the value true or false of the checkbox:

```
public void valCreatorKCSupport(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component, Object value) {          
        utils.printToConsole(this.getClass().getSimpleName().toString() + " - valCreatorKCSupport(...), value = " + value.toString());
        String msg = null;
        if (value.toString().equals("false")){
            msg = matterProp.getProperty("gen_KCSupport");          
            FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(msg);
            throw new ValidatorException(message);
        }       
    }
```

I notice that this validation blocks the behaviour of other components e.g. the opening of dialog boxes.

For other controls I have a similar approach where the required property is based upon which component (buttons) have initiated the call to the server:

```
<xp:this.required><![CDATA[#{javascript:return ( submittedBy('btnSendToCommitee') || submittedBy('btnForCompletion') )}]]></xp:this.required>
```

I tried to set up a similar approach for my checkbox:

but then I get presented an error message:

Error while executing JavaScript action expression
Script interpreter error, line=2, col=33: Error calling method 'valCreatorKCSupport(com.ibm.xsp.domino.context.DominoFacesContext, com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspInputCheckbox, string)' on java class 'se.sebank.kkom.test.MatterValidators'
Message (text with text from matterProp.getProperty("gen_KCSupport"))

Anyone a suggestion how I should apply some conditional statement to my validator?

Comment: Where's `matterProp` set?

Comment: "validation blocks the behaviour of other components e.g. the opening of dialog boxes" - your problem is in the action to opent that dialog - it should not run through validation phase (if possible)